# Deep Learning with Keras - no learning rate with training

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm creating my first model with Keras on Stock data using technical indicators as input to the model and noticed that I see nearly no learning rate - no change in Loss and no change in Accuracy.
As I'm new to DL and Keras I might overlook something obvious, but looking for some help here.

Code snippet and training output below:

```
# Model definitions
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=3))
model.add(Activation(activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
data = trainingsetdata.as_matrix()
labels = trainingsetlabel.as_matrix()
score = model.evaluate(data, labels, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
print(score)
model.fit(data, labels, batch_size=32, epochs=100, validation_split=0.05, verbose=2)
score = model.evaluate(data, labels, batch_size=32, verbose=1)
print(score)

[0.694263961315155, 0.4875]
Train on 380 samples, validate on 20 samples
Epoch 1/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6939 - acc: 0.4605 - val_loss: 0.6900 - val_acc: 0.4000
Epoch 2/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6934 - acc: 0.5079 - val_loss: 0.6882 - val_acc: 0.6000
Epoch 3/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6867 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 4/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6929 - acc: 0.5289 - val_loss: 0.6858 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 5/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6929 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6850 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 6/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6928 - acc: 0.5263 - val_loss: 0.6841 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 7/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6927 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6836 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 8/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6926 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6828 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 9/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6925 - acc: 0.5105 - val_loss: 0.6823 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 10/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6925 - acc: 0.5079 - val_loss: 0.6816 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 11/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6923 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6808 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 12/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6923 - acc: 0.5105 - val_loss: 0.6800 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 13/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6923 - acc: 0.5105 - val_loss: 0.6793 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 14/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6922 - acc: 0.5105 - val_loss: 0.6789 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 15/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6922 - acc: 0.5105 - val_loss: 0.6783 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 16/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6780 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 17/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6922 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6774 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 18/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6771 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 19/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6768 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 20/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6922 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6768 - val_acc: 0.7000
Epoch 21/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6766 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 22/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6764 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 23/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6762 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 24/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6922 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6762 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 25/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6761 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 26/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6759 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 27/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6758 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 28/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6757 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 29/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6757 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 30/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5158 - val_loss: 0.6758 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 31/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6756 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 32/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6922 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6757 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 33/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6756 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 34/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6755 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 35/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6757 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 36/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6755 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 37/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6754 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 38/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5158 - val_loss: 0.6752 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 39/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6750 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 40/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5158 - val_loss: 0.6749 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 41/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6749 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 42/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6749 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 43/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6749 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 44/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5158 - val_loss: 0.6748 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 45/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5158 - val_loss: 0.6749 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 46/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5263 - val_loss: 0.6746 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 47/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6746 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 48/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6745 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 49/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6744 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 50/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6744 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 51/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6747 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 52/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6745 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 53/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6746 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 54/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6747 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 55/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6747 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 56/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5158 - val_loss: 0.6747 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 57/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6745 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 58/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 59/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 60/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 61/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 62/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 63/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 64/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 65/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 66/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 67/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 68/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500

Epoch 69/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5158 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 70/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 71/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 72/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 73/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6739 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 74/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 75/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 76/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 77/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 78/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 79/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 80/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 81/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 82/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 83/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 84/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 85/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5158 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 86/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 87/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 88/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 89/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6743 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 90/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 91/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 92/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5184 - val_loss: 0.6739 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 93/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6740 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 94/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5211 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 95/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6740 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 96/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6921 - acc: 0.5263 - val_loss: 0.6738 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 97/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5263 - val_loss: 0.6739 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 98/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 99/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5237 - val_loss: 0.6742 - val_acc: 0.6500
Epoch 100/100
 - 0s - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5132 - val_loss: 0.6741 - val_acc: 0.6500
400/400 [==============================] - 0s 63us/step
[0.6910193943977356, 0.5275]
```

Comment: I'm quite confused about what are you asking for. Are you asking where can you define the learning rate for the RMSProp optimization algorihtm? or are you asking for suggestions on why your model is not learning to solve your problem at hand?

Comment: I was indeed asking why my model was not learning. Milind below answered the question. I added his suggestion, still do see not much learning, but this might have to do with the data. I have no experience in order to estimate what to expect in terms improvement in Loss and Accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely not sure what is the reason behind the lack of learning in your model, there can be so many reasons for that. An explanation of your problem at hand would help and might be key to understand why the model is not learning. I'm gonna make some intial guesses regarding input data and machine learning theory:

**Input data**

1. Is input data properly normalized along all features? If features have not been normalized (or standarized) one feature might have a much greater range of values and eclipse the rest of features, so the model just takes into consideration one feature.

**ML theory**

2. I would try using a model with at least 2 layers with non-linear activation functions: The reasoning behind it is that the model will be linear if it does not have, at least, 2 layers with non-linear activations (sigmoid is a non-linear activation).
3. Whenever you are facing a new problem and trying to solve it for first time with a NN, I suggest you to use Adam optimizer. Adam is the something like the "fully automated version" of all optimizers. It might not be the optimal choice in some cases but, in my experience, is the best first optimizer to try it out since it works well out-of-the-box.

Hope this guides you a little bit and helps to make the model learn something.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm trying to implement a stock prediction model in Python/Keras from a research paper. I have indeed normalized the input accross all features. Good suggestions on the model and the optimizer which I will try out.

Comment: @hesemani Please, say something when you get those new results.